# How can I set cell font colour in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a C# Winforms application where I need to set the cell font colour programmatically. If a condition is met, the font should be red. I have confirmed the condition check is correct, the problem is in the line

```
 dgv_Table.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Where "cell" is the cell I'm currently checking. This does absolutely nothing. Even if I take it out of the loop and check like this:

```
dgv_Table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

It still does nothing. The lines of code are in a helper function called during Main().

If I set DefaultCellValue, that does change the view, but is not what I want.

```
 private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv_Table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        dgv_Table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
                if (cell.OwningColumn.Name == "RiskName" && cell.Value.ToString() != "")
                {
                    string wholeText = cell.Value.ToString();
                    int score = Convert.ToInt32(wholeText.Substring(wholeText.IndexOf("[") + 1, wholeText.IndexOf("–") - 1));
                    if (score > 300)
                    {
                        dgv_Table.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: were do you try to apply this change? what event?

Comment: When the form is loaded it goes through and should change the appropriate cells.

Comment: have you tryed to call `Invalidate()` on the DataGridView?

Comment: I presume your datagridview is bound. If so where do you fill the source? in the form constructor?

Comment: In the constructor, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was tying this to another event. Because the DataGridView was inside a TabControl and wasn't in the main tab, I ran the check when the TabControl was clicked on.

Probably not best practice and certainly not ideal, but it works now.

Comment: you could try to do this logic in the cellFormatting event i think. Would be better than you actual solution

Comment: You didn't say anything about your TabControl, however this is a good experience +1

Answer (score 0):

This kind of Property (ForeColor or BackColor ...) should be changed in a `Form Load event handler` (or Form Shown)... or in some other event handlers of your `DataGridView`, I think the reason may be your DataGridView rows are not ready, I guess you placed your code in a Form constructor.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //place your code here
   dgv_Table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: It was in the constructor but I put it in form_load and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Shay but mine works, I think you should post more code, I've encountered this problem before, for DataGridView, there are some properties we should initialize in a Form Load event handler.

Comment: @Shay you should be sure that your Form Load event handler is registered with your Form Load event, copying my code and pasting don't work.

Comment: Edited question to add form_Load code and it is registered with the event.

Comment: @Shay try setting some break points in your `Main_Load` and see if the execution jumps in there?

Comment: If I tie it to another event (clicking a random button), it works, but it still doesn't in Main_Load.